# php convert Unicode NCR to original

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, ncr

In Wordpress, when adding a new category with a Chinese/Cyrillic charters i get a slug that looks like %e5%85%ac%e5%af%93 (this is how is saved in Mysql).

How can i convert back this string into original charters (Chinese, Cyrillic , Hebrew etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't PHP's [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) enough?

```
php> echo urldecode('%e5%85%ac%e5%af%93')
公寓
```